# ListView inside FlexView not extending to show all records Xamarin.Forms

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, scrollview, vertical-alignment

I have a problem with rendering ListView inside FlexView.

I have FlexView inside ScrollView as there is a lot of content.

Inside FlexView at the end there is ListView.

ListView implement its own ScrollView by default but it has no focus since there already is ScrollView wrapping the FlexView.

I would like to expand the ListView so all the records are visible, or give focus to ListView's scrolling when the main scroll reaches the end of page but I cannot get it to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to set the Height of your ListView.HeightRequest = ItemsCount * RowHeight

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try. Does it require rows to be fixed height? I have model where each record is shown on three rows and they are not always equal heigh t

Comment: My workaround is best fit for fix row height. For dynamic height, you need to drill little deep for total height calculation.

Comment: Yeah. I think I will manage. Thanks a lot

Comment: FYI! ListView inside a scroll is not a good practice you should avoid that always

Comment: There actually is nested scrolling option available. You can disable parent ScrollView when your ListView gets focus. It needs an override but it works like a charm. Nothing is possible until somebody does is for the first time. Suddenly everybody starts doing it.

Comment: Apply this to all the positive stuff only!